# How to form a dictionary from list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, key-value-coding

I have a list of tuple such as:

```
iList = [('FirstParam', 1), ('FirstParam', 2), ('FirstParam', 3), ('FirstParam', 4), ('SecondParam', 5), ('SecondParam', 6), ('SecondParam', 7)]
```

I want to make a dictionary which should look like:

```
iDict = {'FirstParam': 1, 'SecondParam': 5}{'FirstParam': 1, 'SecondParam': 6}{'FirstParam': 1, 'SecondParam': 7}{'FirstParam': 2, 'SecondParam': 5}{'FirstParam': 2, 'SecondParam': 6}{'FirstParam': 2, 'SecondParam': 7}{'FirstParam': 3, 'SecondParam': 5}{'FirstParam': 3, 'SecondParam': 6}{'FirstParam': 3, 'SecondParam': 7}{'FirstParam': 4, 'SecondParam': 5}{'FirstParam': 4, 'SecondParam': 6}{'FirstParam': 4, 'SecondParam': 7}
```

so `iDict` forms all the possible combinations from `iList`.

`MyExp` will be the key for the dictionary which I'm going to form. Hence in the end it should be

```
Dictionary = dict(itertools.izip(MyExp, iDict))
```

I'm trying to generate iDict first and I tried

```
h = {}
[h.update({k:v}) for k,v in iList]
print "Partial:", h
```

I was hoping to get

```
Partial: {{'FirstParam': 1}, {'FirstParam': 2}, {'FirstParam': 3}, {'FirstParam': 4}{'SecondParam': 5}, {'SecondParam': 6}, {'SecondParam': 7}}
```

from where I would have proceeded ahead to get actual `iDict` and then `Dictionary`.
But instead I got the following output.

```
Partial: {'FirstParam': 4, 'SecondParam': 7}
```

Can anyone tell me where exactly my logic went wrong and how should I proceed further?

Comment: You can only have one value for one key in a dictionary, so you end up with the *last* value for each of your two keys.

Comment: What you want is not a dictionary. It resembles a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iDict isn't going to be a dictionary. It can't, as the keys are repeated. By definition, dictionaries have unique keys. Instead, I'm going to guess that you really want iDict to be a `list` of dictionaries, with every combination of `'FirstParam'` and `'SecondParam'` represented as one of the dictionaries.

So first, we're going to want to break up your list of tuples into two lists, one with all the `'FirstParam'` tuples and one with all the `'SecondParam'`.

```
iList = [('FirstParam', 1), ('FirstParam', 2), 
         ('FirstParam', 3), ('FirstParam', 4), 
         ('SecondParam', 5), ('SecondParam', 6), 
         ('SecondParam', 7)]

first_params = [i for i in iList if i[0] == 'FirstParam']
second_params = [i for i in iList if i[0] == 'SecondParam']
```

Now we need to take every combination of these two lists and form a dictionary out of them, and then put those dictionaries in a list. We can do all of this in one statement, using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to take all the combinations of parameters, converting the tuples that `product` returns into dictionaries using [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict), and doing it for all the combinations with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
from itertools import product

result = [dict(tup) for tup in product(first_params, second_params)]

print(result)
# [{'FirstParam': 1, 'SecondParam': 5},
#  {'FirstParam': 1, 'SecondParam': 6},
#  {'FirstParam': 1, 'SecondParam': 7},
#  {'FirstParam': 2, 'SecondParam': 5},
#  {'FirstParam': 2, 'SecondParam': 6},
#  {'FirstParam': 2, 'SecondParam': 7},
#  {'FirstParam': 3, 'SecondParam': 5},
#  {'FirstParam': 3, 'SecondParam': 6},
#  {'FirstParam': 3, 'SecondParam': 7},
#  {'FirstParam': 4, 'SecondParam': 5},
#  {'FirstParam': 4, 'SecondParam': 6},
#  {'FirstParam': 4, 'SecondParam': 7}]
```

Comment: This works but is there any other way to generate
`first_param = [('FirstParam', 1), ('FirstParam', 2), ('FirstParam', 3), ('FirstParam', 4)]`

`second_param = [('SecondParam', 5), ('SecondParam', 6), ('SecondParam', 7)]`

Is there any other way to separate the list like this instead of directly hardcoding it to be equal to 'FirstParam' and 'SecondParam'?

Comment: Sure, but it all depends on what you're doing/what you're data is like. One idea might be to pass through the list of tuples first and add all the param strings to a `set`, and then pull from that set.

Comment: `for key, group in itertools.groupby(iList, operator.itemgetter(0)):
    print (list(group))`
Thus I was able to fetch out two lists of tuples. Any idea how to 'store'  these in separate lists?? I just read online. But I'm not sure how exactly (list(group)) gives the list.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatley thay cannot be put in one big dictonary because you cannot have duplicate keys in a dictionary (and you would have multiple 'FirstParam' and 'SecondParam' keys). If you want to create a list of mini-dictionaries (each with keys 'FirstParam' and 'SecondParam') then:

```
iList = [('FirstParam', 1), ('FirstParam', 2), ('FirstParam', 3), ('FirstParam', 4), ('SecondParam', 5), ('SecondParam', 6), ('SecondParam', 7)]

first_params = [] #list for collecting all first params
second_params = [] #list for collecting all second params

#Assuming tuple is all first params and then all second params, can only loop through once (more efficient)
i = 0;
while(i < len(iList) and iList[i][0] == 'FirstParam'):
    first_params.append(iList[i])
    i+= 1
while(i < len(iList) and iList[i][0] == 'SecondParam'):
    second_params.append(iList[i])
    i+= 1

#Add to the final list of dictionaries
listOfParamDictionaries = []
for i in range(0, min(len(first_params), len(second_params))):
    listOfParamDictionaries.append({first_params[i][0] : first_params[i][1], second_params[i][0] : second_params[i][1]})
```